# Removing duplicate TEXTS from large mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mysql table, which has structure

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| content    | longtext         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| valid      | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I need to remove duplicate entries by `content` column, everything would be easy if it wasn't longtext, the main issue is that entries in that column vary in length from 1 char to over 12,000 chars and more, and I have over 4,000,000 entries, simple query like `select id from table where content like "%stackoverflow%";` takes 15s to execute, what would be best approach to remove duplicate entries and not wait 2 days on executing query?

Comment: Use select max(id) as max_id from yourtable group by content. Then all content will be unique and you can use max_id to get back all the columns in yourtable. Still this may take time to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

md5 is your friend here. Make a separate `hashvalues` table (to avoid locking/contention with this table in production) with columns for the `id` and `hash`. The primary key for this table should actually be the `hash` column, rather than `id`.

Once the new empty table is created, use MySql's [`md5()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5) function to populate the new table from your original data, with the original `id` and the `md5(content)` for the field values. If necessary you can even populate the table in batches, if it would take too long or slow things down too much to do it all at once.

When the new table is fully populated with data, you can `JOIN` it to itself like this:

```
SELECT h1.*
FROM hashvalues h1
INNER JOIN hashvalues h2 on h1.hash = h2.hash and h1.id <> h2.id
```

This should be **MUCH** faster than comparing the `content` directly, since the database only has to compare pre-computed hash values. I'd expect to run almost instantly. It will tell you which records are *potential* duplicates. There is still a potential for hash collisions, so you also need to compare this back to the original data to be sure, or include an `originalcontent` column in the new table you can use with the query above. That done, you will know which records to remove.

This system can be even better if you can add a column to the original table to keep the `md5()` hash of your `content` field up to date every time it changes. A [Generated Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) will work well for this if you have the right storage engine. Otherwise, you can use a trigger. This column will allow you to re-run your duplicates check as needed, without all the extra work with the separate table.

Finally, there are also `Sha()`, `Sha1()`, and `Sha2()` functions that might be more collision-resistant. However, the `md5()` will be much faster and the additional collision resistance isn't enough to avoid the need for also comparing the original data. This also isn't a security situation where collision potential will matter, and so `md5()` is the better choice here. These aren't passwords, after all.